# Unresolved function or method for pipe()

Tags: node.js, pipe, phpstorm, webstorm

I'm trying to write a simple file web file server. I'm using PhpStorm.

```
var http = require('http');

var fs = require('fs');

function send404Request(response) {
    response.writeHead("404", {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    response.write("404 Page Not Found");
    response.end();
}

function onRequest(request, response) {
    if (request.method === 'GET' && request.url === '/') {
        response.writeHead("200", {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        fs.createReadStream("./index.html").pipe(response);
    } else {
        send404Request(response);
    }
}


http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
console.log("file server is now running...");
```

However, PhpStorm says "unresolved function or method pipe()"

Here is my setting for JavaScript libraries in PhpStorm:

[image: PhpStorm JS Libraries]

Any idea where goes wrong?

Comment: This is the new Boston tutorial lol same exact problem right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Settings/Project Settings/JavaScript/Libraries, Download "node-DefinitelyTyped". This work for me. I had the same issue as your.

Comment: If nothing else works, I updated to the latest version of Webstorm and it did the trick

Answer (score 1):

In the end of 2019 faced the same issue but in my gulpfile.js.

- i got the "Unresolved function or method pipe()" and
- the "Unresolved function or method require()" error messages in PHPStorm.

Downloading the @types/gulp library in PHPStorm resolved both issues.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to wait for the stream to open:

```
var readStream = fs.createReadStream("./index.html");

readStream.on('open', function () {
    readStream.pipe(response);
});
```

Additionally, add this to catch any errors that might be going on:

```
readStream.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err.message);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a workaround I am using. Instead of 
`fs.createReadStream("./index.html").pipe(response);`

I am using: 
`response.write(fs.readFileSync("./index.html"));`

This works well for **intelliJ IDEA**.